# Suggested edit that fixes "obvious" typos rejected as changing intent of answer

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

This is the edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6329635

What I did was fixing obvious typos that wouldn't let the code run at all.

- Adding a missing comma
- Fixing an Angular dependency injection
- Changing `<lide-item>` to `<slide-item>` which was clearly the intent of the answer (it's `<slide-item>` elsewhere in the answer).

I'm sure this was a mistake and that the reviewers simply didn't have time to read it carefully (I don't blame them).

Is there a way to say `take another look` other than posting a new question on Meta? I noticed many other similar questions on Meta and I'd hate to add yet another duplicate, but I don't see any other way.

Comment: Changing actual code is always tricky. *Maybe* that typo was exactly the OP's problem. In this specific case, that was probably not the case; but in general I'd point typos in code out in a comment and let the OP check and fix it themselves.

Comment: I placed a comment on the answer and ask him to review the edit.

Comment: I'm dead against changing code whether it be an answer or a question the correct course should be, comment point out the typos and let the author change it. By leaving a comment you're highlighting that it maybe incorrect not just to the author but to anyone who reads the answer.

Comment: *"Adding a missing comma"* yeah that's a *"typo"*, *"Fixing an Angular dependency injection"*...hmm not so much.

Comment: @Lankymart It does *sound* too intrusive, but it really isn't. In the original answer, the function arguments were correct but did not match the injector arguments (the string annotations). I simply copy-pasted the function arguments into the annotations, which is an "obvious" thing to anyone familiar with Angular.js. (Either way, I learned my lesson and will not edit code in the future.)

Comment: @imgx64 edit code.  Add comments that far exceed the amount of code edited to describe why it was not changing the intent and/or do a comment first pointing out the problem and ask the OP if they mind you change it.

Comment: IMO ***never change the code in a post.*** If it has errors, the community will handle it.

Answer (score 29):

While one *can* correct obvious typos even in code (at least if it is either in an answer or obviously not part of the problem), doing so is error-prone, and likely to be rejected.

Iff you think it is obvious enough, *and* you provide a concise but thorough edit-summary, you might try it (though don't be too disappointed if reviewers disagree).

A comment is likely more appropriate, and won't be rejected (though it might get ignored, at the posters peril).

Looking at your specific edit, it seems to be a bit more than *just* correcting obvious typos. I wouldn't accept it, myself (unless it was my own post, perhaps).

Comment: It depends on what you consider *"obvious"* and is open to interpretation, which is why I'd suggest leave a comment and nothing more. Direct code edits shouldn't be encouraged in my opinion.

Answer (score 14):

Agree with what [Deduplicator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278753/3187556) said, for the most part, but i'd like to add that that kind of edit is valuable.

However, when editing code, **always always always** say **exactly** *what* and *why* you are changing it in the edit summary. There's plenty of room in there - use it!

If you do, reviewers who are actually paying attention are more likely to approve it.

Answer (score -3):

Typo's like that could actually be the cause of the OP's problem.
Don't "fix" typo's in an OP's code and don't add missing code.

You can only really help the OP with those by making him aware of the issue (In a comment), so he can fix those problems with the question, himself.

However, if there's an typo in the description / question, feel free to correct it.

Now, if a answer copies typo's from the OP, or introduces new bugs, comment on that answer as well, pointing out the errors. Don't change those, either.

Basically, don't edit code, unless the formatting is horrendous. (No indentation, stuff like that)

Comment: Note that that edit was on an answer, not the question.

Comment: Just to make sure, is fixing code in **answers** acceptable or not?

Comment: @imgx64 I wouldn't do that given the fact that we *trained* our reviewers to reject such edits...

Comment: @Mat: I think one still shouldn't edit that code. Just poke the person who posted it with a comment.

Comment: Ok it maybe an answer not a question but this doesn't deserve the down-votes it's getting.

Comment: Hm, -3 seems kinda harsh.

Answer (score -21):

**Answer edits considered harmful.**

There's a reason to edit a question: help the asker get a good answer, which makes people happier all around (and the site's content gets better).  Posting a better question of your own would improve the site's content, but *doesn't help the asker*.

If you think an answer is not good enough, though... just post your own.  You improve the content of the site.  And make the asker happier with a better answer.  If it was such a big problem your answer will get upvoted and accepted.  If they still upvote and accept the other "worse" answer... maybe your edit wasn't as essential as you thought.

What would be a reason to edit an answer that is better than a comment or an answer of your own?  Or just downvote it.  Spend those points!

I also find typos annoying, but I'd rather live with them than have answer edits.

After a comment prompted me to clarify my answer, I'd like to add that the reason I think it hurts is because it discourages people from answering. I don't like seeing someone else's name next to mine in my answer because what it says is "That answer was wrong, but fortunately I was here to fix everything". For a typo. Or whatever else. I just don't like it. 
And again, it's completely unnecessary because there are plenty of mechanisms already to get the point across (downvote, comment, post another answer).

Comment: Most edits to my answers are good, valid improvements, catching mistakes or typos in my answer, by someone who understands my answer and caught an error. It would be silly to duplicate my answer with typos removed. Now, a small percentage fix "typos" that are not typos; those are harmful. Others change format / style needlessly, which could be considered harmful (I intended that to be in iambic pentameter). Only a very small percentage of edits (at least to my answers) change the "intent" of the answer in any important way. Is it different for you?

Comment: I very specifically say I'd rather go with typos unfixed in answers, and you defend answer edits by saying how silly it is to duplicate an answer to fix the typos.  Yes, it's silly.  How about my actual point?  How does it help anyone to not post a better answer as an answer?  It's the same with answers as comments instead of posts.  Just post it as an answer!

Comment: I was unable to identify the harm caused by edits of answers.  Could you describe why you find them bad?  All you seemed to have described is 'I would rather you do X', then conclude 'Y is bad, but editing answers is worse!'  You havr failed to describe the **harm** from the answer edot.  My comment tried to describe the many cases where there seems to be no harm, and the rare cases there does.  Without that (why edits are harmful), where is your point?

Comment: Yes, it discourages people from answering.  I don't like seeing your name next to mine in my answer because what it says is "That answer was wrong, but fortunately Yakk was here to fix everything".  For a typo.  Or whatever else.  I just don't like it.  And again, it's completely unnecessary because there are plenty of mechanisms already to get your point across (downvote, comment, post another answer).

Comment: Now, I'm not saying there aren't _some_ useful cases, but, like with `goto`s, my point is I'd rather do away with the "feature" completely, rather than put up with people using it in a way I don't like.  That's my point.

Comment: Ok.  Mind if I edit your answer to include the reason you don't like any edits?

Comment: Very funny. I do, for the record. >_<

Comment: @Victor The whole reason there's an edit option on answers is so they _can_ be corrected. You would rather someone copy your hard work to fix two misspellings than just edit your small typos? Especially if they get the credit for it? I could very much be wrong, but I would guess that you would very much not like for me to copy your answer and just change the spelling of a word or two here. Edits are meant only to improve answers, and to keep the noise level low. If you have two or three answers saying the exact same thing, how are they of any value?

Comment: I would like to add that if someone edits your answer, and you disagree with the edit, you can roll it back. Your answer will return to how it looked before. As the answerer, you have that power and can decide if an edit is harmful to your answer or not.