# Suggested edit rejected because it was "intended to address the author of the post" - although it wasn't

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

Recently I've found an error in the code of [some SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9255093/2202101), which crashes the app. The error is just a method parameter, which the original answer author didn't provide, but which is required. The parameter is crucial, since without it the app crashes.

In short, instead of `public void TextViewClicked()` it should be `public void TextViewClicked(View v)`.

I [decided to edit the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12523514) to add the missing parameter. I wrote the following commentary for it:

> There should be one parameter with View, otherwise the exception would be thrown.

However, my endeavour was met up in arms by edit reviewers and it got quickly rejected, mainly on the following basis:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

But what I think I didn't meant to address the author of the post in any meaningful way, I just fixed the error. So I decided that this reject may be a work of some hasty reviewers, who don't realize why the edit was suggested in the first place.

With this in mind, I [suggested exactly the same edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12559206) for a second time, although with much more alarming comment:

> Added crucial parameter! This edit isn't intended to address the author of the post, this is essential addition, without it app will crash once button is clicked!

This time the edit also was rejected, however with a different rationale:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

This one got me even more confusing. The edit was not make *drastic changes*. What I tried is just to add one method parameter to the answer's code, which will render it work. It's just 6 characters long. How do the reviewers determined it is *intended to address the author of the post* or it even *deviates from the original intent of the post*?

Maybe there is something I'm missing, thinking that the edit review is performed by the ignorant people who don't care about the actual purpose and just want to make quick reputation points?

Comment: FYI, Edit Reviews don't reward any rep points. Only editing does.

Comment: Okay, then maybe this is badges they are after.

Comment: I think you raise a fair point, but the question's title is going to antagonize people. Maybe you could change it to "why was my edit rejected"? Or "Code in answer causes crash, how can I edit this"?

Comment: Thanks for your support, I feel I may get a bunch of downvotes because of this question title, but I don't really care about reputation and more importantly I feel it need to be so. I hope I can get the valid points why the system works like that.

Comment: You don't get rep on Meta anyway. But I think you do want people to see your side of the issue. A more neutral wording could help there.

Comment: There is a fairly neutral wording in the question body itself. Hope someone make it through the title to the actual question. Funny enough, the whole situation with this Meta question strongly reminds me the described edit case, since the people just downvoting me because of a title and don't get to know what's wrong. That's how my edits were rejected.

Comment: Let's not jump to conclusions about why it was rejected. Code changes to highly upvoted answers are dangerous. We do have editors who try to "improve" code in answers and make breaking changes. That's why some reviewers tend to be conservative.

Comment: That's why some reviewers, who don't have idea how the code works and not spend a second to figure out how it should work (not to say to test it themselves) just reject such edits. "It may break things, we don't know for sure so let's just reject it". The fun fact is that my code actually makes code work.

Comment: Try searching, this is discussed on a monthly basis. Apparently the consensus is _"We'd rather have answers containing incorrect code than allowing users to edit code, because the latter adds more problems"_.

Comment: Okay, thanks for a summary. Then I'd rather restrict myself in correcting the code, since there is such a consensus, just to save my time. Question is closed.

Comment: `they will upvote it and make it more visible` that's good, but having the correct code in the answer body is inherently better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems at hand. The first is that there is an epidemic of badge-hunting robo-reviewers, who have two modus operandi:

- An edit contains no changes to code: approve.
- An edit contains changes to code: if it's only whitespace, approve. Otherwise: reject.

You seem to have followed [Suggested edit that fixes "obvious" typos rejected as changing intent of answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278707/suggested-edit-that-fixes-obvious-typos-rejected-as-changing-intent-of-answer) exactly, and there are still some sensible reviewers, but the age-old "50/50" of getting a code edit approved is nowadays more like "20/80". Perhaps submit the edit once again, but note you're then risking an edit ban.

"But", they say, "the reviewers don't have to be Subject Matter Experts". Well, I say, if they don't understand an edit, let them click "Skip", and leave the review to someone who does know what they're doing.

The second problem is that the process to get an indisputable<sup>*</sup> error in an answer fixed is tedious, if not ridiculous. You have three options:

1. Leave a comment pointing out the typo, then:

   1. Hope the OP is still alive, reads it, and follows it up, or
   2. Hope that some Subject Matter Expert comes by and decides it would be a good thing to incorporate that comment into the post.
2. When under 2000 reputation: submit an edit suggestion. As you've noticed, this works maybe 1 out of 5 times.
3. Post your own answer without a typo.
4. Gain 2000 reputation, apply the edit yourself, and hope nobody sees what you did. An awful lot of edits go by unnoticed.

Like option 2, option 1 also never works. I've seen plenty of highly-upvoted answers-with-typos, and the comments pointing out the typo also being upvoted, and in all those years of voting and commenting nobody took the effort to fix the two-character typo.

Option 3 makes no sense at all to me. Assuming the answer in question is good, it addresses the problem at hand, it might even be accepted by the asker, it just contains a minor typo. Then adding the same-ish answer only to fix the typo is only going to get you scolded for answering a question that has already been answered, with an answer that has already been given.

So there's just one option: wait until you have 2K rep and apply the edit yourself.

Do note that according to [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code), this was a valid edit after all:

> **Editing Code in Answers**
>
> Unlike questions, making an answer work is a good thing and should be encouraged with a few guidelines to follow. [...]
>
> **Do:**
>
> [...]
>
> - Fix syntax errors and typos

This was a typo by omission (leaving out a required parameter for an event handler). So it should just have been approved, or skipped when unsure.

The fear of editing code in answers (and accompanying auto-rejection by reviewers) is just caused by the overzealous application of *"Don't edit code, because you might change its behavior which the original poster then has to support or rollback"*. That rule does not apply to this case.

**So**, to all the downvoters and "No, we should never edit code!" shouters, what are we doing here? Building a knowledge base accompanied with working example code, or playing *"Who can interpret the rules the most rigidly"*?

<sub><sup>*: I'm not an Android SME, otherwise I would have applied this edit we're talking about to the answer. It does seem though that `View v` is a required parameter on click event handlers.</sup></sub>

Comment: That's explains it. Thanks. Obviously there is a problem with the system itself, that need to be reformed. I wonder who downvotes this useful post from a veteran, some folks who got embarrassed by it?

Comment: @ayhan _code-edits are discouraged_: I didn't saw anywhere on SO that code edits are discouraged. If I had seen it, I will probably get refrained myself from a suggestion of a code edit. Obviously, this is a _tacit agreement_, but we need an _official_ one.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud Stack Overflow is community moderated, so you can't get an official agreement.  But it was the community (through the years) that has decided that code edits are to be avoided.  Although this idea has become more and more stringent in recent years.

Comment: @psubsee2003 _you can't get an official agreement_: and still there are official guidelines [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: @TranslucentCloud correct, those are the standard guidelines for editing, but the way the help center is set up, the kind of "rules" we're talking about here are traditionally not reflected here since it was a community decision and can be very dynamic (both between individual users and over time).  And since there isn't 100% agreement either (the split votes on this answer are a good example), it is hard to put it in writing.

Comment: Effectively, you are recommending that your expertise (and others) may be applied to others' scores who don't deserve it, and should not get up votes.  Keep in mind, had the edits been accepted, it wouldn't be obvious to any user (without reviewing the edit history) that it was missing this parameter to start with.  If the code would literally **fail** (and not just because of a couple of characters, which _I_ consider a typo) then the answer is wrong and should be worked on by the OP.

Comment: @gravity reputation is a side-effect. As I stated in my answer, as far as I know, we're still collectively building a knowledge base, and I think editing errors out of other's answers is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

You've two main choices if you see an incorrect answer

- Add a comment and see if the creator of the answer agrees and is prepared to update the answer
- Write your own answer with the code you think is correct.

Reviewers are not expected to be subject matter experts in every question topic, they can't therefore tell whether your code edit is good or bad and they are supposed to reject such edits.

Comment: `Reviewers are not expected to be subject matter experts in every question topic`, then maybe such reviewers should be prohibited from reviews by rules? This is site for programmers after all. We expect some subject expertise from people who review our code.

Comment: If we had a new or unpopular tag then nobody would be able to review it and it  edits would never be approved. Because we forbid code changes we don't need subject matter experts.

Comment: Am I understood it right, that you implying the review system on SO works great and the case of mine is perfectly correct?

Comment: I'm saying that the reviewers are following the rules as stated in the help centre and calling them ignorant is unwarranted.

Comment: I agree that calling all the edit reviewers is unwarranted, in fact it's just bunch of reviewers of my edits, which I may legitimately call so. And since the title has a question mark in the end, this is an opened question which I ask, and community will decide if reviewers are mostly ignorant or overall not ignorant and I just had a bad luck.

Comment: From the same link: _"to correct minor mistakes"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster but reviewers are not equipped to evaluate that are they when the mistakes are code mistakes?

Comment: Reviewers are a problem of their own. They smash the Approve button when there's no code change, and Reject when there's more than a whitespace change in a code block. They don't function beyond that.

Comment: The commonly advised workflow is to leave a comment pointing out the typo, and then hoping the OP is still alive, reads it, and follows it up, or that some Subject Matter Expert comes by and decided it would be a good think to incorporate that comment into the post, which is just about the most ridiculous workflow there is to getting things fixed.

Comment: @CodeCaster but that's pretty much what they are expected/told to do no? What's wrong with If you an answer is wrong, write one that isn't?

Comment: @CodeCaster _"to correct minor mistakes"_: honestly I do not consider the mistake in question minor if it crashes the app.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud then write your own answer, as it attracts upvotes and the existing presumably answer attracts downvotes we'll all know which one to use.

Comment: That's ultimately not _right_, in my opinion. The popular question is right, except of a small code bug. Why should I rewrite it in it's entirety as mine answer?

Comment: Because if your edit was wrong the original answer would unfairly start attracting downvotes. And there's plenty of people would ignorantly change code thinking they are fixing it when in fact they would be breaking it.

Comment: Then these so called reviewers should check my improved code, on their own computers. That's not a problem of edit posters if their improvements cannot be reviewed by professionals. It's a problem of the system, how to make that edit reviewers actually care for code. Maybe there should be some form of a collective responsibility for a mistakenly approved code edit.

Comment: As reviewer, you see suggested edits from all over the site, in a massive load of languages. We can't expect reviewers to be familiar with every single language out there, not to mention being able to _run_ the code. If the code in an answer is wrong, comment on that answer or post an answer of your own. __This is just how the site works,__ @TranslucentCloud.

Comment: @Cerbrus, if it is how the site works, then something should be changed to enhance this work. Now it works far from efficiently.

Comment: The fact that reviewers can keep up with the amount of suggested edits that appear in the review queue indicates that the system is actually working quite efficiently. Besides, if the system was somehow improved, you still shouldn't suggest edits like the one being discussed here.

Comment: @Cerbrus don't go claiming that the review system works just because the queues are empty.

Comment: @CodeCaster: The queues being empty is an indication that the system is as efficient as it needs to be. I didn't say the review system was perfect. I'm well aware of the robo-reviewers problem. It's far from perfect, but it works.

Comment: @Cerbrus _The queues being empty is an indication that the system is as efficient as it needs to be_ if the main criterion of the _efficient_ system is a number of edits processed, then yes, the system works great.

Comment: Once again, I'm not saying the system can't be improved, @TranslucentCloud.